# add_column not adding columns to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I've used the `add_column` function from `library(tibble)` in my script, and it shows up fine in the console, but in the actual data frame `df`, it doesn't show that I've actually added any columns. The current structure of my data frame is a     60 x 17, but when I'm done adding my code shown below, it will end up being a    60 x 19, but when I use the following code, it doesn't give me any errors, and it still doesn't show the added columns.

```
add_column(df, 'Reading Depth'= extractdepth , .after = 1)
add_column(df, 'Half Depth'= halfdepth , .after = 2)
```

Any idea on how to get both of my new column added to the data frame?

Comment: Are you saving the results?  I.e., `df <- add_column(df, ...)`?

Comment: This solved my problem. I tried assigning it to `df` using brackets, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[as Nathan points out above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754561/add-column-not-adding-columns-to-data-frame/48754764#comment84509829_48754561); you need to either update your object or create a new object.

Before you get to that you should however, always!, first load packages needed,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

Second, also always, creating some date, here very inspired by `?add_column`,

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)
```

Third, almost always, show the data,

```
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     3
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     3     1
```

great! Now to some solutions.

Solution one, an option where we crate a new object,

```
df_new <- df %>% add_column(z = 1:3, w = 0)
df_new
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       x     y     z     w
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     1     0
#> 2     2     2     2     0
#> 3     3     1     3     0
```

Solution two, a solution where `df` is updated,

```
df <- df %>% add_column(z = -1:1, w = 0)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       x     y     z     w
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3    -1     0
#> 2     2     2     0     0
#> 3     3     1     1     0
```

Note that `<-` is used to write into or crate a new object – [as Nathan's comment pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754561/add-column-not-adding-columns-to-data-frame/48754764#comment84509829_48754561).